# C# LdapConnection Authentication Issue

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, service, ldap

We use code similar to the following to setup a secure connection to an LDAP directory:

```
using (LdapConnection con = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(ConfigReader.ADServer, 636)))
{
    con.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
    con.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate = new VerifyServerCertificateCallback(ServerCallback);
    con.Credential = new NetworkCredential(UserDN, UserPwd);
    con.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
    con.Bind();
}
```

During testing, we noticed the following expected behavior:

- Valid UserDN and valid UserPwd results in successful Bind()
- Invalid UserDN with a valid UserPwd results in Bind() error (The
  supplied credential is invalid.)
- Invalid UserDN with a Invalid (non-blank) UserPwd results in Bind()
  error (The supplied credential is invalid.)

Unfortunately, we also noticed the following unexpected behavior:

- Valid UserDN and blank UserPwd results in successful Bind()
- Invalid UserDN and blank UserPwd results in successful Bind()

Please advise why the LDAP connection is successful with a blank password.
Thanks,

Comment: Is your LDAP server set to allow anonymous binds?  See this link, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816788(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the idea ... but our network administrator confirmed that anonymous LDAP bindings have not been enabled.

Comment: Based on our research, the ability to successfully bind to LDAP without a password (even when the “allow anonymous LDAP bind” setting is disabled) appears to be an LDAP “feature”.  As such, and in hindsight as a general good practice, we implemented a simple check to programmatically handle the blank password condition rather than relying on LDAPConnection.

Comment: @Seymour @gpmurthy could you help by putting the format for the connection string as well username and password an example would do. I am in same situation by am sure my connection string is incorrect. I am trying to connect over ssl usin `LDAP://192.168.1.100:389/ou=People,dc=company,dc=com` do i need to specify port number ? do i need to prefix with ldap ?

Comment: I think a best way would be to return con.Bound property that is correctly set in cases with blank password.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like the connection is bound but is not authenticated till a actual request is sent.

Consider the following to send the request after binding the connection...

```
 using (LdapConnection con = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(ConfigReader.ADServer, 636)))
{
    con.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
    con.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate = new VerifyServerCertificateCallback(ServerCallback);
    con.Credential = new NetworkCredential(UserDN, UserPwd);
    con.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
    con.Bind();
    **con.SendRequest(new SearchRequest(targetLocation, "(objectClass=*)", System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchScope.Subtree, null));**
}
```